# How to access all users from firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to access all users data in firebase, and I want to assign each user their perspective data and append all of these users in users array. Here is the method I used:

```
var users = [User]()

func fetchUserData () {
   var user = User()

   Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
     if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
        self.users.append(user)
    }
  }, withCancel: nil)
} // End fetchUserData Method
```

I know that my User class has to be exactly as the database, otherwise it won't work. Here is what I have for the user class:

```
public class User : NSObject{
  var email: String?
  var first_name: String?
  var last_name: String?
  var profile_picture: String?
}
```

And here is my database structure:

[image: fire base setup]

But I keep getting this error, sometimes the error is referring to email, sometimes first_name, I think it is just random:

[image: appDelegate Error]